# Pairwise ks test by groups

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data as an example and looking to do pairwise ks test (`ks.test`) by grope (ROI and GII) and seasons using the variable Tvalues

```
   season  Tvalues LCZ  gr
1    Fall 44.61303   F ROI
2    Fall 44.62756   F ROI
3    Fall 44.63439   F ROI
4    Fall 44.71301   C ROI
5    Fall 44.59594   C ROI
6    Fall 44.16783   F GII
7    Fall 43.42613   F GGI
8    Fall 43.56969   F GII
9    Fall 44.49767   B GII
10   Fall 44.81384   B GII
11   Fall 44.72411   F ROI
12   Fall 44.63097   B ROI
13   Spri 44.49938   B ROI
14   Spri 44.41650   B ROI
15   Spri 44.57543   B ROI
```

The output should be something like this for D_value

```
             F_GII_Spri  C_GII_Fall  B_GII_Summ
 F_ROI_Spri    29            0.53      41
 C_ROI_Fall     7             24       27
 B_ROI_Wint     5             24       27
```

And one for p_values

I have tried `pairwise_ks_test` from `DataScienceR` but could not get the D_values. Is it possible to do by dplyr where I can get both p-values and D_values

Comment: The expected output you showed is not based on pairwise, as the rownames and column names are different.  It is between two sets

Comment: It is a good question, but please help us answer it by providing more data and show us at least one example how create the `D_values` for one pair like `F_ROI_Spri` and  `F_GII_Spri`.